# how to save data into has_many_through table while saving parent object with nested_form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, has-many-through

i have job model, skill model and job_skill model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :job_skills
      has_many :skills ,through: :job_skills
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_skills


class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :job_skills
    has_many :jobs ,through: :job_skills
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_skills


class JobSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :skill
     belongs_to :job
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :job
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :skill
```

And jobs controller

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @job = Job.new
       @job.job_skills.build
    end

    def create
      @job = Job.new(job_params)
      @job.save
    end

  private
   def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:occupation, :industry, :location,job_skills_attributes:[])
   end
```

and job form is

```
= form_for @job do |f|
   = f.label :location
   = f.text_field :location     
 .clear  
   = f.label "industry*"
   = f.text_field :industry
 .clear  
   = f.label :occupation
   = f.text_field :occupation
 .clear
   = f.label "Skill Required*"
   = f.fields_for(:job_skills) do |s|
    = s.select :skill_id, Skill.all.collect{|p| [p.skill, p.id]},{}, {:multiple => true, :class=> "chosen-select multiple-select-skills"}
= f.submit "submit"
```

only job get save. jobs_skills doesnt save. in job params i get only jobs data. what could be the reason. please help.!!

Comment: While saving job job_skill must be save automatically.but it does'nt happen

Comment: You have to use nested_form_for instead of form_for.

Comment: nested_form_for is undefined method. ..you mean i have to use nested_form gem.right?

Answer (score 0):

Update your **form_for** to **nested_form_for**

```
= nested_form_for @job do |f|
   = f.label :location
   = f.text_field :location     
 .clear  
   = f.label "industry*"
   = f.text_field :industry
 .clear  
   = f.label :occupation
   = f.text_field :occupation
 .clear
   = f.label "Skill Required*"
   = f.fields_for(:job_skills) do |s|
 = s.select :skill_id, Skill.all.collect{|p| [p.skill, p.id]},{}, {:multiple => true, :class=> "chosen-select multiple-select-skills"}
```

Comment: nested_form_for is undefined method. ..you mean i have to use nested_form gem.right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You should use nested_form gem for that.

Comment: still it does'nt saving skill...only saving job

Comment: Update your question with server log for better trace

Answer (score 0):

In this case `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is not required.

Your **models** should be

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_skills
  has_many :skills ,through: :job_skills

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_skills
  has_many :jobs ,through: :job_skills

class JobSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :job
```

And jobs **controller**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @job = Job.new
    #@job.job_skills.build #=> No need of buid
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @job.save
  end

  private

  # Add skill_ids to job_params
  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:occupation, :industry, :location, skill_ids:[])
  end
```

and job **form**

```
= form_for @job do |f|
  = f.label :location
  = f.text_field :location     
  .clear  
  = f.label "industry*"
  = f.text_field :industry
  .clear  
  = f.label :occupation
  = f.text_field :occupation
  .clear
  = f.label "Skill Required*"
  = s.select :skill_ids, Skill.all.collect{|p| [p.skill, p.id]},{}, {:multiple => true, :class=> "chosen-select multiple-select-skills"}
  = f.submit "submit"
```

Hope this will be helpful